# Kripke models - prove that formula is not tautology in intuitionistical logic

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, intuitionistic-logic

My teacher proved that following formula is not tautology in intuitionistical logic:
$$\neg(p\wedge q)\Leftrightarrow (\neg p\vee\neg q)$$
Is it sufficient to show (and we try to do it) that $$\neg(p\wedge q)\Rightarrow (\neg p\vee\neg q)$$   is not tautology.
My teacher wrote red and black formulas. **My** formulas are green  - there are formulas that to my eye my teacher forgot to write.
I know that teacher give arbitrar Kripke model. Tell me please:
1. If my green "supplement" is correct ?
2. From what my teacher conclude red formulas ?  When it comes to black things I know that it is about kripke model.
[image]

Comment: To my limited knowledge, it is a tautology.

Comment: @mathlover, even in intuitonistical logic ?

Comment: In intuitionistic logic, whenever the claim $A \lor B$ is present, you always know *which* is true.  So from $\lnot(A \land B)$ you know that you can't construct both...but you don't know which one can't be constructed.  It could be that $A$ is not constructible, it could be that $B$ is not constructible, or it could be that both aren't.  You can't deduce $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$ because you aren't given enough information to know which isn't constructible.  That's obviously not a formal proof, just some intuition behind why that direction doesn't work.

Comment: tell me please If I correctly write green formulas.